# How to pass feature file path dynamically from command Line?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

How to pass cucumber feature file path dynamically from command Line with TestNG.

Comment: Add the command you are currently using and what is the issue?

Comment: Pass the `--help` option to print out all the available configuration options:
`java cucumber.api.cli.Main --help`